# Determinant of a matrix with generalized binomial coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}\binom{-1/2}{1}&\binom{-1/2}{0}&0&0&...&0\\ \binom{-1/2}{2}&\binom{-1/2}{1}&\binom{-1/2}{0}&0&&...\\...&&&\binom{-1/2}{0}\\ &&&...&&\binom{-1/2}{0}\\ \binom{-1/2}{n}&\binom{-1/2}{n-1}&\binom{-1/2}{n-2}&\binom{-1/2}{n-3}&...&\binom{-1/2}{1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
How can I calculate $\det A$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you define $\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}$?

Comment: @ZurLuria http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series

Comment: @Mark If it is homework, it is very likely that you learned some methods in your lecture. If you do not tell us which, we can evalute the determinant, but we will not be able to tell you how YOU could calculate the determinant.

Comment: In reality I was studying a math problem, and digress, I thought about this problem. But I can not calculate the determinant. I am trying with the Laplace and Gauss, unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would replace $-\frac12$ by a positive integer $N$, prove the result $\binom {N+n-1} n$ by induction on $N$, and then since both sides are polynomials, plug in $N=-\frac12$.

(Call the determinant $f(n,N)$. Just add the $(n-1)$th row to the $n$th row, then the $(n-2)$th row to the $(n-1)$th row and so on, you will get $f(n,N)=f(n,N+1)-f(n-1,N+1)$ which enables us to give an induction proof for the result $\binom{N+n-1}n$.)

An alternative to the induction proof is to regard it as a special case of the second Jacobi-Trudi formula for Schur functions.

I want to prove that 
$$\det_{1\le i,j \le n} \binom{N}{i-j+1}=\binom{N+n-1}n.$$

For an elementary symmetric function $e_k(1,1,\dots,1)$ with $m$ variables equals $\binom{m}k$ whereas $h_k(1,1,\dots,1)=\binom{m+k-1}{k}$. The second Jacobi-Trudi formula gives

$$s_{\lambda}=\det_{i,j=1}^{\lambda_1} e_{\lambda^\ast_i+j-i}.$$

So, if we choose the partition $\lambda=(n)$ and evaluate at $N$ ones, we get:
$$\det_{i,j=1}^ne_{1+j-i}(1,1,\dots,1)=s_{(n)}(1,1,\dots,1)=h_n(1,1,\dots,1)=\binom{N+n-1} n$$ as desired.

Again, because it is a polynomial, we can plug in $N=\frac12$.

---

Edited to add:

Both arguments end the following way:

The determinant with $-\frac12$ replaced by $N$ is a polynomial in $N$ of a certain bounded degree (it is not necessary to actually determine it, the important thing is that the degree does not involve $N$, it is not hard to see that the degree is $n$, but it is also enough to bound it by a more obvious bound like $1+2+\dots+n$).
The resulting binomial coefficient is also a polynomial in $N$ (of degree $n$).

We have proved that the two polynomials are equal as long as we plug in positive integer values for $N$. But these are infinitely many values and two polynomials who agree on infinitely many values (or agree on degree plus one values) are identical.

Since the two polynomials are identical, we can plug in $-\frac 12$ (or $\pi$ or $2+i \dots$).

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand. If you apply the mathematical induction on N, how can I replace $N=-1/2$?

Comment: You can first prove it for all nonnegative integers $N$ by induction, and then use the fact that it is a polynomial identity in $N$ to conclude that it holds with $N$ being a formal variable.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I have another doubt. I do not understand why we consider $\binom {N+n-1} n$ instead of $\binom {-1/2} k$.

Comment: Because the final result is $\binom{-\frac{1}{2}+n-1}n$.

Comment: i.e. $\det A= \binom{-\frac{1}{2}+n-1}n$?

Comment: @Mark Yes, but we know that from the other answer. Polynomial answers are pretty amenable to guessing by computer algebra system.

Comment: @Phira I have done the calculations, using mathematical induction, and I accepted your answer. Thank you. One more please, if possible, what is the logical step that allows me to put $N = 1/2$, after applying mathematical induction? You wrote of polynomial identity but I have not yet understood. Maybe there is something that escapes me because of my bad foundations of mathematics.

Comment: @Mark I have added some details at the end of my answer. This kind of argument is common in combinatorial proofs of identities. One interprets the identity as counting something for positive integers and then concludes that it is a polynomial and therefore true for all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A quick computation in Mathematica suggests that $\det A_n = \binom{n - \frac{3}{2}}{n}$.  I would imagine that a proof would involve row operations to convert the matrix into lower triangular form, then taking the product of the main diagonal entries.  We would begin from the bottom row and work our way up.  Unfortunately I don't have the time for writing out a complete solution.